# How can I redirect using a PHP script called from an SSI?

Tags: php, apache, redirect, wamp, ssi

On a WAMP server, I have a server-side include in a file, a.shtml, composed of the following code:

```
<!--#include virtual="./req.php"-->
```

The contents of req.php are:

```
<?php
Header("Location:index.php");
echo "still here";
?>
```

When I open a.shtml, I see the text `still here`, but the page has made no attempt to redirect itself.  Why is this?  And is there any way to make it work?

Thanks for the help

**EDIT:**  The reason I want to do this is because I have some session variables that I want to influence the way the PHP script acts.  If the session variables are not set, I need it to redirect to a login page.  I know I can just write the entire thing in PHP, but I'd like to do it this way if possible.  If it's *not* possible to change header information from an included PHP file from SSI, then I'll just do it entirely in PHP.

Comment: If you switch on warnings, you will probably see a "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent".

Comment: @Tomalak I've added the code `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the script but am receiving no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. it's impossible
2. you don't need that.

just address tour script that set session variables directly, not through ssi

Comment: @Shrapnel:  1.  _Why_ is it impossible?  The other PHP scripts I run through SSI work just fine.

Comment: LOL, *the other PHP scripts* :))) that's funny

Comment: I'm sorry if there was ambiguity in what I said.  What I meant to say was that when I include (apparently) any other variety of PHP code via an SSI (like abc.php that has the code `echo 1+2+3;`), it works just fine.  So why doesn't a header change work?  And why are there no errors?

Comment: because `Location:` is not a "PHP script" but an **HTTP header**. and there are no HTTP client to interpret that.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to understand.  I was really just trying to do it to see if I _could_ more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

MAYBE (with capital letters Lol), you can pull this off if you call that script in an IFRAME and that IFRAME outputs some JScript like `window.parent.location = <some_url_here>` forcing its parent to change its location... Its just fast-thinking from my part, I might be wrong with IFRAMEs' parent-child relation to the original document, as I haven't tested the "idea" myself :)

Comment: No, I'm sure you're right--this would probably work, Shehi, although I want to make sure that we stop any server-side scripts from running.

Answer (score 0):

If your req.php returns the following html code, the redirect will happen:

```
<html><head>
<title>HTTP 301 This page has been moved</title>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=https://www.example.com/index.php">
</head>
<body></body></html>
```

But: "Google Warning: Using The Meta Refresh Tag Is Bad Practice"